# Systemd Journal fails to open /run/log/journal file

Tags: linux, systemd-journald

I was playing with BPF tools today and ran the command `sudo opensnoop-bpfcc -x -U` and noticed many traces like this:

```
0     403    systemd-journal    -1   2 /run/log/journal/5c01742aed6d4d58bed5f1671e612657/system.journal
```

... and then I ran:

```
$ ls -al /run/log/journal/
total 0
drwxr-sr-x+ 2 root systemd-journal 40 Jun 28 15:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root            60 Jun 28 15:06 ..
```

... and then:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep run
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=6554292k,mode=755 0 0
```

Why would journald try to access a file in a location that just doesn't exist, on a temp filesystem mount? Is something configured wrong? This also happens to a second machine running the same OS listed below. The correct location is `/var/log/journal/` where the path exists.

My system specs:

```
$ sudo lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ uname -a
Linux 5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 10:28:31 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I found the same issue right now in one of my servers.